# Cocoapods don't install or update

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I downloaded a client project that uses pods versioned in the project but when I run pod install or update, I receive this error:

[!] The `IMFormatsAndValidations` pod failed to validate due to 2 errors:

```
- ERROR | attributes: Missing required attribute `homepage`.
- ERROR | attributes: Missing required attribute `source`.
```

Any one know how can I solve this problem? 
How add this Missing attribute

Comment: Try adding --private option.

Comment: Sorry @VJayakarEdidiah but how can I add this --private option?

Comment: After much searching I found a file called Gemfile , is a file used for describing gem dependencies for Ruby programs . A gem is a collection of Ruby code que we can extract into a "collection " which we can call later .

After installing dependencies , no longer had this error.
So be sure to look for Gemfile file and check if you possessed the same versions installed on your computer.

Could this help: http://bundler.io/rationale.html

Comment: The issue here. `pod install` refuses to install private pods which do not have full information in their podspec and `pod install --private` also fails with `Unknown option: '--private'` . So, how do I use CocoaPods with private pods that do not have homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Insert the below lines in the podspec file

```
s.summary = 'Librairy summary'
s.homepage = 'http://your.librairy.homepage'
```